# Using MQTT with PubNub

Tags: mqtt, pubnub

I'm trying to send MQTT messages to PubNub using the MQTT Gateway. I followed [this tutorial](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2014-07-08-mqtt-now-supported-by-pubnub/) but I can't get it to work.

I wrote 4 programs:

- MQTT Subscriber
- MQTT Publisher
- PubNub Subscriber
- PubNub Publisher

I managed to get both PubNubs programs to talk each other. Also, I can see MQTT published messages on the MQTT subscriber program. But MQTTs programs and PubNubs programs do not seem to communicate.

- PubNub --> PubNub ✔
- MQTT   --> MQTT ✔
- PubNub --> MQTT ✘
- MQTT   --> PubNub ✘

I don't think is a code problem. I wrote the apps in javascript, python and go. I also tried the **mosquitto_pub** and **mosquitto_sub** clients with no success.

This is my configuration for the MQTT applications:

```
publish_key   = "my_pubkey"
subscribe_key = "my_subkey"
channel_name  = "test"
client_uuid   = "mqtt-pub"

mqtt_hostname = "mqtt.pubnub.com"
mqtt_id       = publish_key + "/" + subscribe_key + "/" + client_uuid
mqtt_topic    = publish_key + "/" + subscribe_key + "/" + channel_name
```

And the configuration for the PubNubs clients:

```
publish_key   = "my_pubkey"
subscribe_key = "my_subkey"
channel_name  = publish_key + "/" + subscribe_key + "/" + "test"
client_uuid   = "pubnub"
```

And this is how I use the mosquitto_pub client:

```
mosquitto_pub -h mqtt.pubnub.com -t 'my_pubkey/my_subkey/test' -i 'my_pubkey/my_subkey/mosquitto' -m 'Hello from mosquitto'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## DEPRECATED ANSWER

This answer was correct at the time but as of late 2017, PubNub supports MQTT in a scalable fashion same as its traditional Pub/Sub foundation.

See the answer below by @adam

---

## PubNub MQTT Bridge

We have identified and fixed the issue with the PubNub MQTT bridge. If you retry it should be working but reply back here or to PubNub support if it is still not working.

---

## UPDATE - PUBNUB OFFICIALLY SUPPORTS MQTT

PubNub has upgraded (replaced) the MQTT bridge POC (a single endpoint for testing) to scale for real projects that allows you to connect your native MQTT clients directly to the PubNub Network.

Please refer to [New, Improved PubNub MQTT Support and IoT Capabilities](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/new-improved-pubnub-mqtt-support-and-iot-capabilities/) for more details or contact [PubNub Support](http://pubnub.com/support).

Comment: I am still seeing the same issue as Bigomby reported.  Messages going back & forth between the MQTT clients are fine.  But, mqtt client cannot communicate with the pubnub clients.  I assume the client_uuid can be any id as long as the chars are valid.

Comment: My client_uuid is definitely less than 64 chars.  Yet, I am not able to communicate with pubnub clients.  I am tried this with both my program, and with MQTT.fx client.  Communication between my program and MQTT.fx is fine, but the messages do not go to the pubnub client.  And, publishing messages using pubnub rest API will go to pubnub, but not to my program nor MQTT.fx.

Answer (score 0):

## MQTT at Scale with PubNub

I don't think the method using Python and Mosquitto works anymore. If you want to use MQTT and PubNub try the following code with Python and Paho:

```python
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
 
publish_key = "<your publish key>"
subscribe_key = "<your subscribe key>"
client_id = "<your unique client identifier>"
 
 
client = mqtt.Client(client_id=publish_key + "/" + subscribe_key + "/" + client_id)
client.connect("mqtt.pndsn.com", 1883, 60)
client.publish("<topic to publish>", json.dumps({ "hi": 10 }))
```

What this code does is it publishes JSON data to an MQTT topic (channel in PubNub lingo).

Instead of "hi = 10" you can publish data that is suitable for your scenario. I insist on including a Unix timestamp so you know when the data was submitted.

You can also use the [PubNub standard publish with Python](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/python/pubnub-python-sdk?devrel_so=connecting-pubnub-to-freeboard-instance) or any other language that there is an SDK for ([there's more than 70 SDKs](https://www.pubnub.com/docs?devrel_so=connecting-pubnub-to-freeboard-instance)).

```python
import time
from pubnub.pnconfiguration import PNConfiguration
from pubnub.pubnub import PubNub
 
pnconfig = PNConfiguration()
pnconfig.publish_key = '<your publish key>'
pubnub = PubNub(pnconfig)

## makes a timetoken that is easily converted to 
## a JavaScript date object in a web browser
javascript_timetoken = int(time.time() * 1000) 

pubnub.publish().channel("my_channel").message({
    'tt': javascript_timetoken,
    'foo': 'bar'
}).sync()
```

Now that this message has been published it can be received in realtime in your dashboard that is open in a web browser. If the dashboard is not open at the time a message is published, it can be retrieved later using [PubNub storage and playback](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/storage-and-history?devrel_so=connecting-pubnub-to-freeboard-instance).

[image]